# Flashing Gapps on Second Account

Tags: cyanogenmod

I have a rooted Nexus 5 running CyanogenMod 12.1-20150510-NIGHTLY-hammerhead. I created a new user from the top right corner, but it didn't have gapps installed on it. When I try to install, it only replaces the one on the original account. How do I install it on the second account? I have TWRP Recovery

Answer (score 0):

It should've been installed by default. If it hasn't then there is something wrong, do you see the play store if so go to the play store and install the other Gapps.

I think it's because you need to setup the space seperately. So you need to install it from there.